# Cannot execute full outer join?

Tags: sql, join, outer-join

I am trying to execute this query. I'm not trying to use an ON keyword because i want to return all the rows from all 3 tables as one table.

```
SELECT Catalogue, Descriptionx, Quantity FROM pxxxA 
FULL OUTER JOIN
pxxxB 
FULL OUTER JOIN 
pxxxC
```

It is saying "Incorrect syntax near 'pxxxC'."

Answer (score 1):

You still need to include how the `ON` statement, the full outer join will include anything that matched or not.

```
SELECT Catalogue, Descriptionx, Quantity
FROM pxxxA 
FULL OUTER JOIN
pxxxB 
ON pxxxA.column = pxxxB.column, etc.
FULL OUTER JOIN 
pxxxC
ON pxxxB.column - pxxxC.column, etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

When you say "i want to return all the rows from all 3 tables as one table.", if you have

Table 1 with rows 1 and 2 and TABLE 2 with rows A and B, do you want the full set of four possible combinations? "1 A, 1 B, 2 A, 2 B?"

Or two rows as if you had just lined the tables up next to each other? "1 A, 2 B"?

If the full set of combinations, then a CROSS JOIN is what you want. Otherwise you need to specify join criteria on an outer join to line up the rows.